# How to print a date range as a string?

Tags: r, date, date-range

I want to print a date range as string using R.
Following is what I did

```
> startDate <- as.Date("2005-02-02")
> endDate <- as.Date("2005-02-07")
> dates <- startDate:endDate
> dates
[1] 12816 12817 12818 12819 12820 12821
```

Here instead of showing the date as a string as done when we print startDate

```
> startDate
[1] "2005-02-02"
```

It it showing the epochdays.

What I actually want was the string representation of the dates and not epoch days.
I even tried the following without any luck

```
> as.character(dates)
[1] "12816" "12817" "12818" "12819" "12820" "12821"
```

How can I print the date string rather than epoch days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dates <- seq(startDate,endDate,by="day")
print(dates)
```

You may want to look at `?seq.Date`.

Comment: +1 -- Also, to be more explicit: your range has to be of type `Date`, hence `seq()`, your rendering of it will use `format()` (which is invoked by `print()`) which you can do by hand too: `format(dates, "%Y-%b-%d")` just to pick a different style.